# materials lose colour when enabling light in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, lighting

The moment I enable light, I lose colour. I am using the same code as on OpenGL which is working nicely but I get to use glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE); just before glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

Articles I've read mention that you don't need to use that call on OpenGLES, is there some sequence of calls that I am missing?

I should also add I'm using a 3ds file for the model which is working fine until i try and add light.

```
//draw function
//ofSetSmoothLighting()
   glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)

//ofEnableDepthTest();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//ofEnableLighting();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

//pointLight.enable();
    //setup
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_AMBIENT, &/*first member of my aray*/);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_DIFFUSE, &/*first member of my aray*/);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_SPECULAR, &/*first member of my aray*/);

    //on position change
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_POSITION, cc);

    //on orientation
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spot_direction);

    //setAttenuation(1.f,0.f,0.f);
        glLightf(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, attenuation_constant);
        glLightf(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, attenuation_linear);
       glLightf(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, attenuation_quadratic);

    //ofEnablelighting 
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/);

//modelDraw()

//for each mesh 
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, currentMaterial.getDiffuseColor());
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, currentMaterial.getAmbientColor());
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, adjustedSpecular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 128.f * currentMaterial.getSpecularExponent());

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &m_vertices[0] );
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &m_normals[0] );
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &(materialsIter->second[0]));

    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );

//point light disable
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0 + /*my index*/);

//ofDisableLighting()
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_NORMALIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of calls you use to set up your material does not make much sense. You set the material ambient and diffuse colors here:

```
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, currentMaterial.getDiffuseColor());
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, currentMaterial.getAmbientColor());
```

but you also enable `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

Having `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` enabled means that you **do not** use the values for the ambient and diffuse material properties set with `glColorMaterialfv()`. Instead, the values for these properties are taken from the current color, which is the value set with `glColor4f()`.

To illustrate how to use these calls, let's say you want to use a material that has both the ambient and diffuse property set to red. The two options are:

1. Set the individual material properties:

   ```
   glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
   GLfloat color[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, color);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, color);
   ```
2. Use `GL_MATERIAL_COLOR`:

   ```
   glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
   glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   ```

These two options will produce the same result. The advantage of option 2 is that it requires fewer calls, and can be more efficient when changing colors frequently. The limitation is that it's not possible to set different values for the ambient and diffuse properties.

I hope you're aware that OpenGL ES 1.x is an obsolete API, and rarely used anymore.

Comment: thanks. I'm getting some strange results with option 1, I think it's creating a transparency and depth test error as it looks like there is fog in front of the model and wrong sides are displaying when they should be at the back. option 2 works ok, it would be nice to get option 1 working though as I would like to play with different ambient lights. this is how the error looks like now http://imageshack.com/a/img537/3862/OwoiMs.png